# How to sum all discounts collection and then get sum of these value for all students in another collection

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When i test this code to get list for allDiscountForAllStudents, i got an empty list. Why is that?

this is code

```
getAllDiscountForAllStudents() async {
    int _allDiscountForAllStudents = 0;
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('courses')
        .doc(_id2)
        .collection('course_students')
        .where('withdraw', isEqualTo: false)
        .get();
    List allCourseStudents = querySnapshot.docs.toList();

    QuerySnapshot snapshot2;
    for (int i = 0; i < allCourseStudents.length; i++) {
      snapshot2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('discounts')
          .where('Course Id', isEqualTo: _id2)
          .where('User Id', isEqualTo: allCourseStudents[i]['ID'])
          .where('Approved', isEqualTo: true)
          .get();
    }
    List allDiscountForAllStudents = snapshot2.docs.toList();

    print(allDiscountForAllStudents);
    return _allDiscountForAllStudents;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you override the total list with the data of the last student you get and if that one has no data it will be empty. Could you try it with this code:

```
getAllDiscountForAllStudents() async {
  int _allDiscountForAllStudents = 0;
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('courses')
      .doc(_id2)
      .collection('course_students')
      .where('withdraw', isEqualTo: false)
      .get();
  List allCourseStudents = querySnapshot.docs.toList();

  
  List allDiscountForAllStudents=[];
  for (int i = 0; i < allCourseStudents.length; i++) {
   QuerySnapshot snapshot2;
    snapshot2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('discounts')
        .where('Course Id', isEqualTo: _id2)
        .where('User Id', isEqualTo: allCourseStudents[i]['ID'])
        .where('Approved', isEqualTo: true)
        .get();
    allDiscountForAllStudents.addAll(snapshot2.docs.toList());
  }
  

  print(allDiscountForAllStudents);
  return _allDiscountForAllStudents;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it updated the data and code but it returned an empty list

Comment: what i want is, How i can get sum for all discounts collection then get sum these value for all students in another collection

Comment: Can you print the lenght of `allCourseStudents.length` and `snapshot2.docs.lenght` to check if you get any data at all.

Comment: allCourseStudents.length return 8, but snapshot2.docs.length return 0

Comment: That is the reason you list is empty. Your second query doesn't return any data.